Magento 2 : No Such Entity with Cartid when Adding Item to Cart after Upgrade
We have an issue on Magento 2.4.5 where customers get an error saying "No such entity with cartid = xxxx" when they try to add an item to their cart.
Most of the time, this happens after we perform a PHP upgrade. My assumption is that some sort of session identifier is being cleared out during the upgrade, and when the customer comes back to the site, whatever identifier was stored in their cookies no longer matches an identifier on the site.
Has anyone else experienced this, and are there any workarounds or fixes other than asking users to clear their cookies?
